# set up electronic drums in ableton

Tags: drums, recording, ableton-live, electronic-drumset

So, I have Alesis DM Lite electronic drum kit and I also have Ableton Live 9 software. I want to record the drums thorugh Ableton, but I don't know how to set up the drums in the software. The drum kit has a usb port with one end which is like the one for printers (not the regular usb end) and with that I can connect the kit to my computer. When I open ableton it detects that the drum-kit is connected, but I can't make any sounds with it whatsoever. Can someone please explain how to set up the drums in ableton so that it reacts to the signals when I hit the pads?
Thanks! I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Do the instructions not talk you through the process?

Comment: If you have time, can you tell us if you are familiar with MIDI or have any experience with MIDI recording and playback?

Comment: Todd Wilcox, sorry for such a late response, I hadn't noticed that you had commented. No I don't have any experience with MIDI at all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to learn about the basics of ableton live.

first of all, you need to understand drum rack basics.

then you need to understand the MIDI input and output basics in ableton live

or

actually, the simplest way to explain why you're not getting sounds is you did not insert any instrument to your armed monitoring MIDI track.

hope this helps.